# Excel copy to Word VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have some code that I am working on with the macro recorder. In word it always begins with Selection. This article https://exceloffthegrid.com/controlling-word-from-excel-using-vba/?unapproved=9388&moderation-hash=83a9b85f06d7f960463f59103685510b#comment-9388 says I should be able to assign the document to a variable and just insert this before .Selection. However the selection method doesn't appear in VBE for me after I type my document variable. I get a run time error 438 'object doesn't support this property or method' on my first use of the word Selection object (Selection.EndKey). As far as I can see the GoTo method should select the start of the heading.

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
'
' Select data in excel and copy to GIR
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim GIR As Word.Document
    Dim GIRName As String
    Dim GEOL As String
    Dim Tbl As Long
        
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application '<<<  Create a Word application object
    wdApp.Visible = True '<<<< Open word so you can see any errors
    
    GIRName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose GIR to open", _
                                          FileFilter:="Word Files *.docm* (*.docm*),")
    Set GIR = wdApp.Documents.Open(GIRName) '<< call Documents.Open on the word app
    
    'Loop through excel workbook to copy data
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) <> "TEMPLATE" And ws.Visible = True Then
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, "(Blank)", "NoGEOLCode")
            ws.Activate
            GEOL = Range("C9").Value
            Tbl = 1
            Range("A14").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            
            'Paste each worksheet's data into word as new heading
            GIR.Activate
            GIR.Content.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=5, Name:=""
            Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            Selection.TypeParagraph
            Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
            Selection.TypeText Text:=GEOL
            Selection.TypeParagraph
            Selection.Tables.Add Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=53, NumColumns:=7, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
            With Selection.Tables(Tbl)
                If .Style <> "Table1" Then
                    .Style = "Table1"
                End If
                .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
                .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
                .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
                .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
                .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
                .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
            End With
            Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
            Tbl = Tbl + 1
            Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=6, Name:=""
            Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            Selection.TypeParagraph
        End If
    Next
    
    GIR.Save
    
    
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please use the edit link below the question and give more detail: which line gives the error; what is the text of the error message; what is selected in the Word document when the error occurs.

Comment: Since this code is hosted in Excel, `Selection` on its own refers to the Excel version, which of course doesn't have the Word properties/methods.  To get at the Word version use `wdApp.Selection`

Comment: Thanks @chrisneilsen that has solved my first problem. I now have an issue with the code copied from word macro recorder to add a table. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63714379/add-tables-to-document

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code.

1. It is bad practice to use the `Selection` object for various reasons. It is better to use `Range` instead, both in Excel and Word.
2. You set the variable `GIR` to the document you opened but then use `ActiveDocument` instead.
3. You add your table into a paragraph formatted with *Heading 2* style. For table styles to work correctly the underlying paragraph style must be *Normal*. This is because there is a [hierarchy of styles](https://web.archive.org/web/20110221092333/http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-word/archive/2008/10/16/behind-the-curtain-styles-order-of-operations.aspx) in Word with table styles at the bottom, just above document default which is represented by *Normal*.
4. You set the variable `NewTbl` to point to the table you created but make no further use of it.
5. The line With `wdApp.Selection.Tables(Tbl)` will error as there will only be one table in the `Selection`.

I have rewritten your code as below. I have left the final 3 lines of Word code unaltered as I am unsure exactly what you are doing there, a consequence of attempting to debug code without the document being worked on. I have tested this code using some dummy data and it works for me in O365.

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
  '
  ' Select data in excel and copy to GIR
  '
  '
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  
  Dim wb As Workbook
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim wdApp As Word.Application
  Dim GIR As Word.Document
  Dim GIRName As String
  Dim GEOL As String
  Dim Tbl As Long
  Dim NewTbl As Word.Table
  Dim wdRange As Word.Range
  
  Set wdApp = New Word.Application '<<<  Create a Word application object
  wdApp.Visible = True '<<<< Open word so you can see any errors
  
  GIRName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose GIR to open", _
    FileFilter:="Word Files *.docm* (*.docm*),")
  Set GIR = wdApp.Documents.Open(GIRName) '<< call Documents.Open on the word app
  
  'Loop through excel workbook to copy data
  Set wb = ThisWorkbook
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If UCase(ws.Name) <> "TEMPLATE" And ws.Visible = True Then
      ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, "(Blank)", "NoGEOLCode")
      ws.Activate
      GEOL = Range("C9").Value
      Tbl = 1
      Range("A14").Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
      Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
      Selection.Copy
            
      'Paste each worksheet's data into word as new heading
            
      Set wdRange = wdApp.Selection.GoTo(What:=wdGoToHeading, _
        Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=4, Name:="")
      With wdRange
        '      wdApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
        '      wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .End = .Paragraphs(1).Range.End
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .MoveStart wdParagraph
        .MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
        '      wdApp.Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
        .Style = GIR.Styles(wdStyleHeading2)
        '      wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=GEOL
        .Text = GEOL
        '      wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Style = GIR.Styles(wdStyleNormal)
        Set NewTbl = GIR.Tables.Add(Range:=wdRange, NumRows:=53, _
          NumColumns:=7, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, _
          AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow)
        '    With wdApp.Selection.Tables(Tbl)
        With NewTbl
          If .Style <> "Table1" Then
            .Style = "Table1"
          End If
          .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
          .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
          .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
          .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
          .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
          .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
          .Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatPlainText
        End With
        '    wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
        '    Tbl = Tbl + 1
        wdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst, _
          Count:=6, Name:=""
        wdApp.Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
        wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
      End With
    End If
  Next
    
  GIR.Save
    
  Application.EnableEvents = True
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
End Sub
```