# Add tables to document

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Hi I get this error 450 when I try to add the table to the word document from excel. I copied the code from the word macro recorder. Have also tried using the syntax here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.tables.add  e.g. Tables.Add(Selection.Range, 3, 5) and setting it to a table object but still no luck.

[image]

```
Sub ExcelToWord()
'
' Select data in excel and copy to GIR
'
'
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
 
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim GIR As Word.Document
    Dim GIRName As String
    Dim GEOL As String
    Dim Tbl As Long
    Dim NewTbl As Word.Table
                
    Set wdApp = New Word.Application '<<<  Create a Word application object
    wdApp.Visible = True '<<<< Open word so you can see any errors
    
    GIRName = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please choose GIR to open", _
                                          FileFilter:="Word Files *.docm* (*.docm*),")
    Set GIR = wdApp.Documents.Open(GIRName) '<< call Documents.Open on the word app
    
    'Loop through excel workbook to copy data
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) <> "TEMPLATE" And ws.Visible = True Then
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, "(Blank)", "NoGEOLCode")
            ws.Activate
            GEOL = Range("C9").Value
            Tbl = 1
            Range("A14").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            
            'Paste each worksheet's data into word as new heading
            
            wdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=4, Name:=""
            wdApp.Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
            wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
            wdApp.Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Heading 2")
            wdApp.Selection.TypeText Text:=GEOL
            wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
            Set NewTbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, NumRows:=53, NumColumns _
        :=7, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:= _
        wdAutoFitWindow)
            With wdApp.Selection.Tables(Tbl)
                If .Style <> "Table1" Then
                    .Style = "Table1"
                End If
                .ApplyStyleHeadingRows = True
                .ApplyStyleLastRow = False
                .ApplyStyleFirstColumn = True
                .ApplyStyleLastColumn = False
                .ApplyStyleRowBands = True
                .ApplyStyleColumnBands = False
            End With
            wdApp.Selection.PasteAndFormat (wdFormatPlainText)
            Tbl = Tbl + 1
            wdApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToSection, Which:=wdGoToFirst, Count:=6, Name:=""
            wdApp.Selection.MoveUp Unit:=wdLine, Count:=1
            wdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph
        End If
    Next
    
    GIR.Save
    
    
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
   
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Range:=wdApp.Selection.Range, ...`  same issue as your previous question

Comment: Thanks again @TimWilliams hope you are well. Would I be right to think I can replace wdApp.Selection with my GIR document variable? I think previously I was doing GIR.Selection.Type... etc so that may be why I had issues.

Comment: `GIR.Selection` will error. `Selection` is part of `Application` not `Document`.